# adding SalesOrderItem to SalesOrder in NetSuite SuiteTalk Web Services

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite

I am trying to place a simple SalesOrder using NetSuite web services and having zero luck with what I would assume is a very simple process:

First I instantiate my objects for use with the web service:

```
SalesOrder order = new SalesOrder();
SalesOrderItemList items = new SalesOrderItemList();
SalesOrderItem item = new SalesOrderItem();
```

Now you would think I would just look for some method like:

```
items.Add(item);
```

To create my list of SalesOrderItems but now such method exists, or anything similar that I can seem to wrap my head around.  I have the SuiteTalkWebServices Platform Guide and have read it through and I am stumped.

Any good references for this API?  NetSuites is lacking in my opinion.  I am using C# by the way.

### UPDATE:

I found this PDF via a google search, huge help:
http://www.netsuite.com/portal/partners/integration/download/SuiteTalkWebServicesPlatformGuide_2011.2.pdf

What threw me was I need to create an Array then then assign that array to the defined object, instead of adding things to it one by one like I assumed.  The entire API works this way, so once you have it down you are good (basic test adding 2 items to an order):

```
// create sales order
            SalesOrder so = new SalesOrder();
            SalesOrderItem[] orderItemsArray = new SalesOrderItem[2];

            for (int i = 0; i < orderItemsArray.Length; i++)
            {
                SalesOrderItem item = new SalesOrderItem();
                item.quantity = i;
                item.description = "test item" + i;
                item.amount = (double)75.00;
                orderItemsArray[i] = item;
            }

            SalesOrderItemList orderItems = new SalesOrderItemList();
            orderItems.item = orderItemsArray;
            so.itemList = orderItems;

            so.orderStatus = SalesOrderOrderStatus._pendingApproval;
            service.add(so);
```

There is more that needs to be done with this but at least this should get anyone going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Answer to your references question, there are several resources that may help.

- [Netsuite User Form](https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/forumdisplay.php?f=24) - This forum gets pretty quick replies and Netsuite employees will often reply to questions (registration required, but free)
- I have written a [blog](http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/tag/netsuite/) with many PHP code examples of Netsuite API calls.  It's not C#, but you may still find it useful. (More to the point, here is an example of a [sales order request](http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2012/01/netsuite-webservices-and-multiple-item-sales-orders/))

I would strongly suggest browsing through the Netsuite Usergroup forum, it has a lot of code examples.

Comment: can you explain this line of code to me? $items[] = $SalesOrderItem;  This makes no sense to me.

Comment: That is PHP code for adding a item to an array.  $items is an array variable and $items[] = $SalesOrderItem appends the Sales Order Item to the end of the array.  I have only used the PHP_Toolkit, so I am not sure how directly it transfers into the C# Libraries.

Comment: I actually find code samples in any language a lot more helpful than the sketchy documentation that's available - C# is almost the same as modern PHP anyway..

Answer (score 0):

You can still do what you want in a while loop and use a list.  Something like this should work. Using an SQLiteDataReader but you can use any datareader.  This way you can use a reader instead of a datatable or 2 sql statements to get the count of items and the item rows.   I'm going to post before testing and hope it helps others avoid the array count issue and using an index.

```
enter sSQL = string.Format("SELECT Transactionitems.* From TransactionItems Where TransactionId = {0}", transactionid);
SQLiteDataReader drTransactionItems = SQLDB.getDataReader(sSQL, conn);
List<SalesOrderItem> salesOrderItems = new List<SalesOrderItem>();                                        
while (drTransactionItems.Read())
{
    SalesOrderItem item = new SalesOrderItem();
    item.description = drTransactionItems["ItemName"].ToString();
    item.item.internalId =   drTransactionItems["NetSuiteItemId"].ToString();
    item.amount = Convert.ToDouble(drTransactionItems["OriginalPricePerUnit"].ToString());
    item.price = new RecordRef();
    item.price.internalId = Program.RegisterConfiguration.NetSuite_PriceLevelId.ToString();
    item.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(drTransactionItems["Quantity"].ToString());
    salesOrderItems.Add(item);                       
}
drTransactionItems.Close();
salesorder.itemList = new SalesOrderItemList();
salesorder.itemList.item = salesOrderItems.ToArray();
```